# Aligning text with Bootstrap panel-heading text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

"All I'm trying to do" is to align the text above the panel with the text in the panel-header, no matter what the screen size. I've been scratching my head with this one...

[N.B. The full fiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/andysmiffy/8t5v3ux1/)

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
         <h2 class="h2align">Left align with "Panel Title"</h2>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
         <div class="row col-md-6 col-md-offset-2 custyle">
            <h2>
               Panel Title
            </h2>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>Panel Body, yada yada...</p>
     </div>
   </div> <!-- /panel -->
</div> <!-- /container -->
```

Comment: Why you have combined `.row` with Bootstrap's grid classes i.e `col-md-*`?  on a single div. **This is absolutely wrong**.

Comment: That might well be the case, @MuhammadUsman, but that's been added by another developer to solve another layout issue elsewhere... who is better at css than I am, so loathed to rip it all out :)

Comment: Check this [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/8t5v3ux1/4/).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at it @MuhammadUsman. Alas removing that css doesn't work in all screen sizes.